# UserID number not in order after deleting a user

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a table called tblUserLogin.  One of the columns is labeled UserID.  Evertime I add a user it numbers them in order (ex. 1, 2, 3).  If I delete numbers 2 & 3 and then add another user the user has a UserID of 4, the next number in line.  Should it be number 2?  Is this a setting in the properties window that needs adjusted?  Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it absolutely should *not* be 2. It's presumably meant to be a *unique* identifier. If some other system still knows about user ID 2, then when it asks your system for user 2 you should be able to say that the user doesn't exist - not give back information about the wrong user.

Reusing identifiers would be a really bad idea, basically. Once an identifier has been allocated to an entity, there should be no way of the same identifier (in the same context) referring to a different entity, nor should there be any way of changing the identifier used for that entity.

Answer (score 0):

You've not stated which database type you're using, however:

The UserID column is probably an identity column. This means it will take the next value, that has never been used (subject seed and increment settings if you're in sql server).

You can't get this to take unused values without taking on the job of generating these identities yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a SQL Server [IDENTITY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column, then that's the correct and expected behaviour.  However, if you'd like to reuse the deleted IDs from the gaps, take a look at *Example B* from SQL Server Books Online: [Using generic syntax for finding gaps in identity values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)